# How to plot history of the model

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

From [this tutorial](https://stellargraph.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html) code, I'm trying to plot the history of the model using keras library.
But this gives error `KeyError:'acc'`.

This is the part of the code.

```
model.compile(
    optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate, decay=0.001),
    loss=losses.categorical_crossentropy,
    metrics=[metrics.categorical_accuracy],
)

# Train model
history = model.fit_generator(
    train_gen, epochs=num_epochs, validation_data=val_gen, verbose=2, shuffle=False
)

plt.plot(history.history['acc'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_acc'])
plt.title('Model accuracy')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.legend(['Train', 'Test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()

# Plot training & validation loss values
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('Model loss')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.legend(['Train', 'Test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Any advices would be appreciated.

Comment: Your hyperlink doesn't link to a tutorial.

Comment: @MigB this code is 'graphsage-cora-example.py', the GraphSAGE Cora Node Classification Example. you can find it in that link.

Answer (score 0):

Change `acc` to `accuracy` and `val_acc` to `val_accuracy`. and consider to look at [this link](https://keras.io/metrics/)

Comment: Still get the similar error... "KeyError: 'accuracy'"

Comment: could you change `metrics` to  `metrics=['accuracy'])` and then try it with `accuracy` and `val_accuracy` parameters?